# A short story about a fax machine that receives messages from the future

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I am sure I did read in the 80s, in our local library (it doesn't exist anymore by the way), a science fiction short story about an electrician that invented a fax machine that started to receive messages from unknown sources. At the beginning, the electrician, who is superstitious (I am also sure about this), thinks that the messages are coming from the other side (I mean, from the dead) but soon realizes they come from the future. Then, the machine falls into the hands of a villain who threatens to take over the world, but the electrician is able to fax a message that changes something in the future that is reflected as a reply message to the present making the machine to fall in an infinite loop causing its own destruction.

UPDATE: I am uncertain about the following, but I think I remember reading that the fax machine was a Xerox. Also, by the end of the story, when the villain opens the door of his hideout -in a basement- the fax machine is burning with a bunch of paper sheets flying through the air.

By the way, I don't remember any infinite loop created by a Möbius loop or so from the future end, but it was a kind of ping-pong message scheme starting with a request sent by the electrician to the future that generated an echo response to the fax in the present asking to send back a response who also asked an echo request, etc., etc.

I hope someone can help me finding the story.

Comment: check if anything here rings a bell: https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TimeTravelTropes